# How can I visualize the concept of post-incrementing a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

A pointer is a variable that points to a location in memory.

```
int *pointer1;
int *pointer2 = pointer1;
```

Let's say that both variables are pointing to memory location

```
0xA
```

Then I perform

```
pointer2++;
```

Now, `pointer2` points to

```
0xB
```

Because both addresses point to the same place, I fully expect `pointer1` to point to

```
0xB
```

But it does not.  `pointer1` still points to `0xA`.

How is this possible?  Does the pointer have another address to specify which pointer it actually is?  If yes, what is this second address called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are confusing the value stored in the pointer with the value to which the pointer points.

The two pointers, per se, are completely independent, they just happen to point to the same memory location. When you write

```
pointer2++;
```

you are incrementing the value *stored in `pointer2`* (i.e. address to which it points), not the value stored at the pointed location; being `pointer` and `pointer2` independent variables, there's no reason why also `pointer` should change its value.

---

More graphically:

```
int var=42;
int * ptr1 = &var;
int * ptr2 = ptr2;
```

Supposing that `var` is stored at memory location 0x10, we'll have this situation:

```
+----------+
|          |  0x00
+----------+
|          |  0x04
+----------+                      
|          |  0x08               +------------+
+----------+              +------| ptr1: 0x10 |
|          |  0x0C        |      +------------+
+----------+              |      +------------+
| var: 42  |  0x10   <----+------| ptr2: 0x10 |
+----------+                     +------------+
|          |  0x14      
+----------+
|          |  0x18
+----------+
|          |
```

Now we increment ptr2

```
ptr2++;
```

(due to pointer arithmetic the stored address gets incremented of `sizeof(int)`, that here we assume being 4)

```
+----------+
|          |  0x00
+----------+
|          |  0x04
+----------+                      
|          |  0x08               +------------+
+----------+              +------| ptr1: 0x10 |
|          |  0x0C        |      +------------+
+----------+              |      +------------+
| var: 42  |  0x10   <----+   +--| ptr2: 0x14 |
+----------+                  |  +------------+
|          |  0x14   <--------+
+----------+
|          |  0x18
+----------+
|          |
```

Now `ptr2` points to 0x14 (what's there is not important in this example); `ptr1` is left untouched pointing to 0x10.

(naturally both `ptr1` and `ptr2` have an address where they are stored, as any other variable; this is not shown in the diagrams for clarity)

Answer (score 2):

Pointers, although having special characteristics, are numbers. In this respect, it's as if `pointer1` and `pointer2` were integers, which just happened to have the same value. If you increment one, you're not automatically incrementing the other.

Answer (score 2):

`pointer1` is an object that contains values of type `int *`.
`pointer2` is another object that also contains values of type `int *`.

If you change the value contained in `pointer2` there is no reason to think the value in `pointer1` will also change. The exact same thing happens with values of any other type. For instance, with `double`

```
double a = 4.2;
double b = a;
b /= 10;
/* is `a` now 4.2, or 0.42?? */
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line `int *pointer2 = pointer1;` you are copying the address stored at pointer1 to pointer2. Both are independent variables. If you want to update the address stored at pointer1 through pointer2 you will need a pointer of pointer:

```
int **pointer2 = &pointer1;
(*pointer2)++;
```

Comment: And for your second and third questions: Yes, and the pointer1 address is called &pointer1.